# Changing header width in listview sometimes creates a gap

Tags: c#, listview, draw, detailview

I tried to draw a list view and I faced an unusual problem in the detail view. If a user follows the below steps, a gap will appear between the left side of the list view control and the items.

Steps to reproduce:

1. increasing a header(column) width by mouse that create scroll
2. scroll to left
3. decreasing a header width as possible

By following this steps a gap will appear, how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: How could we comment on your drawing and other code when you don't show it?

Comment: @TaW the question is which part of code needed?